# Link to Anchor on another website doesn't work (tested in Chrome)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, anchor, href

I am facing the issue that my anchors seem to work if I'm on the website where my anchors are:

```
<li role="presentation">
    <a aria-controls="k" data-toggle="tab" href="#k" role="tab">K</a>
</li>
```

However, not if I'm trying to jump to a particular section on that website from another website via href. The tab pane is built in Bootstrap.

`domain.com/beamer-lexikon/#k` makes the hyperlink navigate to the page but not to section 'k'.

Section 'k' is marked with id 'k':

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="k" role="tabpanel"></div>
```

Did I get anything wrong?

Do you have any idea where I can start looking for the problem? Javascript, CSS?

Thanks a lot and best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '/' after beamer lexicon, and make sure the target id is declared in the section you are trying to jump to.

Other than that, without seeing your code it will be hard to tell.

```
domain.com/beamer-lexikon#k
```

Comment: @SteffenBrueckner Please paste these details in your question.

Comment: @torazaburo: Yeah, sorry for the mess - changed it now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the Bootstrap framework doesn't support this kind of anchor link. The solution is to implement this piece of code on the page where the anchors are located in the document-ready function:

```
if(window.location.hash != "") {
    $('a[href="' + window.location.hash + '"]').click();
}
```

Best regards,
Steffen